# Why C standard defines range of data types one short?

Tags: c

The C99 standard defines the range of data types in the following manner:

```
— minimum value for an object of type signed char
SCHAR_MIN -127 // −(2^7 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type signed char
SCHAR_MAX +127 // 2^7 − 1
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned char
UCHAR_MAX 255 // 2^8 − 1
— minimum value for an object of type char
CHAR_MIN see below
— maximum value for an object of type char
CHAR_MAX see below
— maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character, for any supported locale
MB_LEN_MAX 1
— minimum value for an object of type short int
SHRT_MIN -32767 // −(2^15 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type short int
SHRT_MAX +32767 // 2^15 − 1
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned short int
USHRT_MAX 65535 // 2^16 − 1
— minimum value for an object of type int
INT_MIN -32767 // −(2^15 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type int
INT_MAX +32767 // 2^15 − 1
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned int
UINT_MAX 65535 // 2^16 − 1
— minimum value for an object of type long int
LONG_MIN -2147483647 // −(2^31 − 1)
— maximum value for an object of type long int
LONG_MAX +2147483647 // 2^31 − 1
— maximum value for an object of type unsigned long int
ULONG_MAX 4294967295 // 2^32 − 1
```

If we see the negative range, it can be actually one more than what is defined here as per allowable two's compliment representations. Why they are defined like this ?

Comment: These sizes are defined in the standard? Which section?

Comment: Two's complement isn't a requirement AFAIK.

Comment: It may be to allow for 1s complement as well as 2s complement.

Comment: I'm not sure if means standard, but rather the ANSI limits.h

Comment: I have copied the ranges from C standard draft.

Comment: @bubble put the link of your font, please.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: @CashCow Are you sure? The questions are entirely different...

Comment: I believe all these sizes are implementation dependent?
the standard only defines for a minimum size doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe so in arithmetic operations, the value that has just the highest bit set is a flag for overflowing if you are incrementing or decrementing by 1. This value also works well as a pseudo-NaN value for integers. The number itself is probably "well-defined" for bitwise operations but not for arithmetic ones.

Comment: @BeyondSora As I read more carefully through the document, these are the minimum values..

Comment: The question [Why does INT_MIN = -INT_MIN in a signed twos complement representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917233/why-does-int-min-int-min-in-a-signed-twos-complement-representation) is **NOT** a duplicate of this question.  The answer there is strictly about 2's complement arithmetic; the answer here is "because there are other systems of binary arithmetic than 2's complement arithmetic:".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If we see the negative range, it can be actually one more than what is defined here as per allowable two's complement representations. Why they are defined like this ?

Because C is also designed for old (and new!) architectures, which don't *necessarily* use two's complement representation for signed integers. Three representations are indeed allowed by the C11 standard (which of these applies is implementation-defined):

> ### § 6.2.6.2 Integer types
>
> If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the following ways:
>
> — the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (*sign and magnitude*)
> — the sign bit has the value −(2<sup>M</sup> ) (*two’s complement*);
> — the sign bit has the value −(2<sup>M</sup> − 1) (*ones’ complement*).

So, with ones' complement representation, the minimum value is `-(2^M - 1)`. However, there is an exception: the C99 optional types `intxx_t`, which are guaranted to be stored with two's complement representation (and that's why there are optional: C standard doesn't force this representation).

Answer (score 4):

Because two's complement is not required. It is possible that C99 could be implemented on an architecture with a sign bit and magnitude or one's complement.

Comment: the C standard only permits two's complement, ones' complement or sign and magnitude as signed integer representation

Comment: @Christoph Is that explicitly stated in the standard or only implied by the minimum values in limits.h? I recall last time I dug into this and read the C11 standard like the devil reads the bible we could even find two's complement assumptions (anecdote warning though, I can't remember where and I can't find the discussion I had about it).

Comment: Do you know if any implementation has ever been created for a practical non-two's-complement platform [not counting virtual machines whose primary purpose is to be able to claim that not all C99 implementations use two's-complement representations]?