# C: What does x = !y mean?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, numbers

I was reading the code for the Catalan numbers algorithms in C and I found the phrase I don't quite understand. Here it is (recursively):

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;

ull catalan2(int n) {
int i;
ull r = !n;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    r += catalan2(i) * catalan2(n - 1 - i);
return r;
}
```

Can someone please tell ma what the phrase 
    r = !n 
is responsible for here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know what `!` does in C?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Comment: `if (n == 0) r = 1; else r = 0;`

Comment: Thank You very much for answers. Now I understand what it does in this code.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
ull r = !n;
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
ull r;
if (n == 0)
    r = 1;
else
    r = 0;
```

A tricky way to do it without the branch:

```
#include <limits.h>
...
ull r = 1-((unsigned)(n|(-n))>>(sizeof(n)*CHAR_BIT-1));
```

Comment: It's quite likely that a good compiler will produce better code for the original formulation than the "branchless" version. Aside from any question about readability. (Tried with gcc: 3 non-branching instructions vs. 5.)

Comment: Although the tricky way appears to have trouble with -INT_MIN, may depend on 2's complement, no padding, yadda, yadda, +1 for adding some fun to the answers.  IAC the 1st 2/3rds of the answers is clear and correct.

Comment: @rici: This "branch way" might yield reduced performance in comparison with that bit-wise operations trick. It really depends on the underlying HW architecture as well as the designated compiler at hand. But it will for sure lead to **inconsistent performance**, depending on the value of `n` and branch-prediction heuristics. The running time of the "tricky way" is guaranteed to be identical on every execution.

Comment: @chux: Thanks. I cant see how this would yield a problem, as `INT_MIN|(-INT_MIN) == INT_MIN`

Comment: @barakmanos: To be clear, the code produced by gcc for intel architecture *has no branches*. It doesn't even use a CMOV; instead, it does a test and then sets the low order bit of a cleared register from the appropriate condition bit. (However, CMOV is not a branch either, and does not incur failed-branch-prediction penalties.) So it will also have consistent execution time, roughly half of your solution.

Comment: @rici: OK, but just to be clear on my side, "it does a test" sounds like branching.

Comment: @barakmanos: `test` is an instruction. Specifically, the code is `xorl %eax, %eax; testl %edi, %edi; sete %al`, which (1) clears the result register; (2) sets the ZF condition code from a comparison of the argument register with itself; (3) sets the low-order byte of the result register from the condition code ZF. (`testl` sets other condition codes as well. But no branches are involved; it's pure bit manipulation.)

Comment: @rici: OK, thank you for the knowledgeable information. I've always been pretty sure that whenever `ZF` is used, a branch follows.

Comment: `INT_MIN|(-INT_MIN)` _may_ result in `INT_MIN`.  That behavior is not defined by C.  [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8917528/2410359)

Comment: Memoizing the naive recursion would obsolete this optimization anyway.

Comment: @chux: Can we not assume that `INT_MIN` is all 1s, hence the bit-wise OR will yield `INT_MIN`?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: What **on earth** does "memorizing the naive recursion" mean in the context of this answer? (I'm honestly puzzled).

Comment: @barak manos 1) "Can we not assume that INT_MIN is all 1s" - not with 2's complement. With 2's complement, `-1` is all 1's 2) `-INT_MIN` by itself may throw an exception.  3) `INT_MIN`, even with 2's complement may be `0b100...001` leaving `0b100...000` as a trap representation.

Comment: @chux: Ooops, that was dumb question to begin with, sorry. What I meant to ask is "can't we assume that `INT_MIN`'s most significant bit is 1, hence the result of the bit-wise OR will always have its MSB set to 1, hence the result of the shift operation will always have its LSB set to 1"?

Comment: @barak manos 1) It is a reasonable assumption, but C11 §6.5 4 "Some operators ..., >>, ... are required to have operands that have integer type. These operators yield values that depend on the internal representations of integers, and have implementation-defined and undefined aspects for **signed** types."  2) bit-wise OR with `(-INT_MIN)` may have throw an exception due to `(-INT_MIN)` before the or-ing occurs.

Answer (score 1):

x = !y means "evaluate y as a boolean and return the contrary boolean value"

So if y is zero, then it is false and we return a true value (ie, 1). Otherwise, y is true and we return zero.

Answer (score 1):

`ull r = !n;` is equivalent to `ull r = n == 0 ? 1 : 0;`. It's accounting for the empty tree when `n == 0`; the for loop counts nonempty trees.

Answer (score 0):

`r != n` means that:  assign `0` if `n` is non-zero else assign `1` to `r`.