# Problem with using limits and very large numbers in C++

Tags: c++, int, limit, long-integer

This was the third or fourth time that encounter this problem and it just annoys me because it makes no sense for me as beginner programmer.

So for my class I had to make a program(function inside a program) that will find largest and smallest digit in a number and return the digit count as a variable. I hate to use references but thats not the point right now.

My program works well, as expected nothing bad is happening until I try to send the largest long long int number to the function.

Because I don't need a negative number inside my function I used an if statment to check if number is <0 and if it is then it should be multiplied by -1 to get a positive(I know that I could use the abs function but same result).

When I pass the largest long long int which is −9,223,372,036,854,775,807 program returns that the number is smaller than 0 but also returns a negative number, not a positive one, but when I test the −9,223,372,036,854,775,807 which is that number -1 everything works again.

So my question is what is actually happening here, why is the n*=-1 part ignored, is it because the number is using all of the memory or ?

```
int Digits(long long int n,int &c_min,int &c_max){

    c_min=9;
    c_max=0;

    if(n<0){
        n*=-1;
    }

    int digit;
    int numberOfDigits(0);

    while(n!=0){
        digit=n%10;
        if(digit > c_max) c_max=digit;
        if(digit< c_min) c_min=digit;
        numberOfDigits++;
        n/=10;
    }



    if(numberOfDigits==0){
        c_min=0;
        c_max=0;
        return 1;
    }

    return numberOfDigits;
}
```

MAIN FUNCTION :

```
int main ()
{
    int mini,maxi;
    int e = Digits(std::numeric_limits<long long int>::min(), mini, maxi);

    std::cout << e;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question is that's simply how two's complement arithmetic works. A Google search will give you all the information you need. But you should also take the following two-part pop quiz: what is `-75 % 10` and `-75 / 10`. After you figure out the answer to this first part, the second part is: can you figure out how to implement your function in a way that works with negative numbers, but does not require that multiplication by -1?

Comment: _When I pass the largest long long int which is −9,223,372,036,854,775,807_ Do you mean `−9,223,372,036,854,775,808`?

Comment: The largest negative number does not have a corresponding positive value so the multiplication by -1 overflows and stays negative.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help It gave me a lot of things to explore I replaceted *=1 with digit=abs(n%10); and it works all fine now,

Comment: This is related to how two’s complement arithmetic works. See [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917233/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you have 4 bits for your number, which means you can store 2^4 numbers, which is 16. Now, since you want positive and negative numbers, you might want to split it in half and have 8 positive, 8 negative numbers. But you also need zero, which means besides zero, you have 15 numbers. What happens is you have numbers from -8 to positive 7, precisely 16 numbers:

```
-8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Now as you can see, you can't have a positive 8 in 4 bits. This is the case here, [The largest negative number does not have a corresponding positive value so the multiplication by -1 overflows and stays negative.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55678108/problem-with-using-limits-and-very-large-numbers-in-c#comment98041282_55678108) Overflow actually causes undefined behavior, meaning you need look no further.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the reason.
The `abs(min())` returns a value that is 1 bigger than max() of a certain type.

For a 32 bit int, `min() returns -2^31, while max returns 2^31 - 1`
For a 64 bit long long int,

```
min() returns -2^63 while max() returns 2^63 - 1
```

So when you do a n = n*-1, it will not hold that number as it overflows.

So the min value you can test is min()+1

BTW, it is higher efficiency to do it this way

```
n = -n
instead of 
n = n * -1
```